# Search simple figure in big figure

Tags: algorithm, search, grid, 2d

I create **big figure** consisting of squares.
Also I have some **simple figures** consisting of squares too.

How can I find my **simple figures** in the **big figure**?

--
*Thanks.*

Comment: I assume you want to find the occurrences of "small figure" in the "big figure"? Right?  Are you trying to find exact matches?

Comment: @ElKamina >> I have 5 "simple figures" and I can my "big figure" form of "simple figures". **Squares located on grid.** Example figures: http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/9948/figuresk.jpg

Comment: Are you looking for *a* match, or *all* matches?

Comment: @0x131313 You could improve the description of the problem. Probably the picture helps, but I cannot access image shack from work. Let me take a look when I reach home.

Comment: @templatetypedef >> I want to collect "big figure" of "simple figures" (without overdubs).

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the squares are located on a grid, you could try simply looping over the grid with each small figure, to see if the corresponding squares are equal.  If so, you've found one instance of a simple figure.

If you want to get fancier, you could encode simple figures as non-intersecting paths, i.e. the first simple figure might be a path like: from start, move right.  Then for each square of the big figure, if you can complete the path and stay on the big figure's squares, you have found an instance of a single figure.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose each row of the big figure, B, is represented by a packed array of bits, and suppose the largest small figure can be contained within a h-by-v grid.  (In your example figure, h=3, v=2.)  Using h*v bits (or a few more, eg 4*2, or 4*4, or 8*2 etc., to get to a convenient size) make a mask M_s for each small figure s.  Move an h-by-v "window" across and down B, at each (x,y) forming a value M(x,y) that represents the bits that are set in B and are in current window.  (This value can be computed incrementally, *ie* by shifting one bit in for each row of the window.)  Whenever `M_s & M(x,y) == M_s`, you have found an occurrence of small figure s.

Note, the method above supposes that blank cells in a small figure are "don't cares", *ie* can match either a blank or non-blank in B.  If such cells are *not* "don't cares", then a complementary map of blanks is needed for each small figure, besides the map of non-blanks used before.  This map tests against the complement of M(x,y).  It is possible to combine the tests together and test for `M_s ^ M(x,y) == 0` instead of for `M_s & M(x,y) == M_s`, if the M(x,y) window is the same size as the small figure.

If B is extremely large and sort of sparse, it may be faster to shift the small-figure patterns and test them directly against words of B, instead of getting bits of B into a value M(x,y); or pre-compute arrays of shifted small patterns.

If the number of small figures is large, sort them such that if small figure u is contained in w, you can skip testing for w whenever u is not found.  Similarly, if both u and v are contained in w, you can skip testing for w whenever either of u or v is not found.  However, optimizations like this and the previous one should only be tried if the basic method outlined in first paragraph is too slow.